# Expanding a widget horizontally inside column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm facing some problem by composing layout of my App.

My widget at the end sould look like this

[image]

This is my code

```
Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: [
      Column(
        children: [
          // Widget A
          SizedBox(
            height: widget.screenHeight * 0.9,
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // Widget B
          Container(
            height: widget.screenHeight * 0.1,
            color: Colors.green,
          )
        ],
      ),
      // Widget C
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.pink,
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
```

I want **Widget A** to occupy 90% of screen height and mantain a 16/9 aspect ratio, **Widget B** to occupy remaining 10% height and have the same width of his sibling, and **Widget C** to fill remaining space

With that code, **Widget A** and **Widget C** are showed correctly, but widget B doesn't fill his space as i expect.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex:4,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

you have to play with the `expanded` widget